# Windows Azure Added Endpoint Doesn't Show up on the Management Page

Tags: powershell, azure

I added an endpoint to a VM in Azure using the following two commands in powershell:

```
Add-AzureEndpoint -Name "foo" -Protocol "UDP" -LocalPort "12345" -VM $vm
Set-AzureEndpoint -LocalPort "12345" -Name "foo" -Protocol "UDP" -PublicPort "12345" -VM $vm
```

I can see the endpoint using powershell (output below), but I don't see it in the manage.windowsazure.com website. Do I need to do something special to get it to show up? Did I not add it correctly? Or half-add it somehow? I notice the others (all added through the website) all have VIP entries, and mine does not. I don't see anything in the documentation about how to set a VIP. Do I need one?

```
Get-AzureEndpoint -VM $vm


LBSetName                :
LocalPort                : 5986
Name                     : PowerShell
Port                     : 5986
Protocol                 : tcp
Vip                      : abc.def.ghi.jkl
ProbePath                :
ProbePort                : 0
ProbeProtocol            :
ProbeIntervalInSeconds   :
ProbeTimeoutInSeconds    :
EnableDirectServerReturn : False
Acl                      : {}

LBSetName                :
LocalPort                : 3389
Name                     : Remote Desktop
Port                     : 51578
Protocol                 : tcp
Vip                      : abc.def.ghi.jkl
ProbePath                :
ProbePort                : 0
ProbeProtocol            :
ProbeIntervalInSeconds   :
ProbeTimeoutInSeconds    :
EnableDirectServerReturn : False
Acl                      : {}

LBSetName                :
LocalPort                : 445
Name                     : smb
Port                     : 445
Protocol                 : tcp
Vip                      : abc.def.ghi.jkl
ProbePath                :
ProbePort                : 0
ProbeProtocol            :
ProbeIntervalInSeconds   :
ProbeTimeoutInSeconds    :
EnableDirectServerReturn : False
Acl                      : {}

LBSetName                :
LocalPort                : 139
Name                     : smb2
Port                     : 139
Protocol                 : tcp
Vip                      : abc.def.ghi.jkl
ProbePath                :
ProbePort                : 0
ProbeProtocol            :
ProbeIntervalInSeconds   :
ProbeTimeoutInSeconds    :
EnableDirectServerReturn : False
Acl                      : {}

LBSetName                :
LocalPort                : 12345
Name                     : foo
Port                     : 12345
Protocol                 : UDP
Vip                      :
ProbePath                :
ProbePort                : 0
ProbeProtocol            :
ProbeIntervalInSeconds   :
ProbeTimeoutInSeconds    :
EnableDirectServerReturn :
Acl                      : {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update your VM object after changing endpoints. Finish off your script with this call:

```
$vm | Update-AzureVM
```